# How to persist the default keycloak database in docker?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image:

```
REPOSITORY                  TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak   18.0.2    ce57c5afb395   5 months ago   590MB
```

I run this command:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
```

but the problem is when I stop the server the realms the users that I created are deleted, how can I create a container?

How to have only one container that I can run, not everytime that I do docker run, a new fresh container is created.
Is there another command?

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: As a side note, you should not use `sudo` to run `docker` or any other command that is not meant to administer the computer.

Comment: @axiac Since you can very easily use `docker run` to compromise the entire host, it's appropriate to require `sudo` permissions for it.

Answer (score 5):

Keycloak uses a H2 database by default, you need to persist the database files in a volume and re-use the volume in subsequent `docker run`'s.

---

1. Create a `docker volume` for the H2 database files

```
docker volume create keycloak
```

2. Set the correct permissions on the new volume (the `keycloak` user in the `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2` image container is `UID: 1000`, `GID: 0`)

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --entrypoint chown \
    -v keycloak:/keycloak \
    alpine -R 1000:0 /keycloak
```

3. Use the docker volume to persist the H2 database

```shell
docker run \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
    -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
    -v keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/h2 \
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
```

Comment: Using with 20.0.2 and all works well. Thanks! Great while learning how to configure KC without losing your changes! ;-)